# Iframe added with jquery show the wrong source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm doing some client-side testing and has the following script running:

Simplified version:

```
$( ".result tbody tr" ).each(function() {
    var orgnr = $.trim($(this).find('[headers=h-personorgnummer]').text());

    var url = 'https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=presenteraKungorelse&diarienummer_presentera='+announcementID;
    $('<iframe />').attr({
        src: url,
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

for each row I open add an iframe to get some data.

In the element-inspector, all the src:s are correct, yet the pages that are shown in the browser all contain the same content. The content of the last or second last node in the table i'm iterating through.

Full version:

```
$( ".result tbody tr" ).each(function() {
    var announcementID = $(this).find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
    var orgnr = $.trim($(this).find('[headers=h-personorgnummer]').text());
    var name = $.trim($(this).find('[headers=h-personorgnamn]').text());
    var company={announcementID:announcementID,orgnr:orgnr,name:name};
    numbers[orgnr] = company;

    //opening the pages
    //bugg, den använde fel announcementID
    var url = 'https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=presenteraKungorelse&diarienummer_presentera='+announcementID;
    $('<iframe />').attr({
        src: url,
        class: 'bolagsverket',
        id: orgnr
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: If you open a new tab and copy/paste one of the *generated* URLs, do they work as expected? They might use a frame buster to prevent iframe hijacking.

Comment: Yes! They work as expected! the native page doesn't have any javascript at all. It's just static html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a redirect running(all frames will be redirected to https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=redirect&forward=main.no.sidebar.presentera ). As the redirect-URL did not contain the `diarienummer_presentera`, it  must be stored on serverside(session).

It seems that something went wrong with the data stored on the server, I'm afraid you can't solve it from the outside.

The only solution that works for me is to use a delay (2 seconds) between the creation of the iframes